# JAX-RS maven project not working with cargo plugin

Tags: java, maven

I have recently switched to IntelliJ idea for my Java Enterprise projects and I have some issues with getting my maven projects to start. I'm using the cargo plugin to get the project up and running quickly, so in my project I ran:

```
mvn clean package cargo:run
```

This resulted in the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-

plugin:1.4.14:run (default-cli) on project rest-server: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.14:run failed: Error while expanding /tmp/cargo/installs/glassfish-4.1.zip
[ERROR] java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
```

Here is my pom.xml.
I think most of the dependencies should be there, so I'm not sure what is meant by the error.

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.readlearncode</groupId>
        <artifactId>dukesbookshop</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>rest-server</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>rest-server</name>
    <url>http://localhost:8081</url>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <javaee-api.version>7.0</javaee-api.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javaee-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <profiles>

        <!-- GlassFish specific version of build -->
        <profile>
            <id>glassfish</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.14</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <container>
                                <containerId>glassfish4x</containerId>
                                <zipUrlInstaller>
                                    <url>http://download.java.net/glassfish/4.1/release/glassfish-4.1.zip</url>
                                </zipUrlInstaller>
                            </container>
                            <deployables>
                                <deployable>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                    <type>war</type>
                                    <properties>
                                        <context>/rest-server</context>
                                    </properties>
                                </deployable>
                            </deployables>
                            <configuration>
                                <properties>
                                    <cargo.servlet.port>8081</cargo.servlet.port>
                                    <cargo.glassfish.admin.port>4881</cargo.glassfish.admin.port>
                                    <cargo.glassfish.jms.port>7681</cargo.glassfish.jms.port>
                                    <cargo.glassfish.domain.jmxPort>8681</cargo.glassfish.domain.jmxPort>
                                    <cargo.glassfish.http.ssl.port>8180</cargo.glassfish.http.ssl.port>
                                    <cargo.glassfish.orb.ssl.port>3881</cargo.glassfish.orb.ssl.port>
                                    <cargo.glassfish.orb.mutualauth.port>3981</cargo.glassfish.orb.mutualauth.port>
                                    <cargo.glassfish.osgi.shell.telnet.port>6681
                                    </cargo.glassfish.osgi.shell.telnet.port>
                                    <cargo.glassfish.orb.listener.port>3781</cargo.glassfish.orb.listener.port>
                                </properties>
                            </configuration>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>


    <build>
        <finalName>rest-server</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <!-- This is needed to tell the unit tests which profile we are running. -->
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Same problem here... Using cargo-maven2-plugin:1.8.2